# MySQL query working in Workbench but not on Visual Studio Table Adapter Wizard

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013, tableadapter

I'm trying to create a `TableAdapter`using Visual Studio Wizard with the following query:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(val_perc,
    '% ',
    description
    ORDER BY val_perc
    SEPARATOR '/')
FROM
    comp
        INNER JOIN
    comp_detail ON id_comp_desc = id_comp_detail
WHERE
    id_comp = 19;
```

When I try to create a `TableAdapter` inside a `DataSet` in Visual Studio it says that my SQL syntax is not correct near SEPARATOR and ORDER BY.
The query works perfectly fine in MySQL workbench.